# Regex with exception inside exception

Tags: regex

I made the following regex :

```
(\w{2,3})(,\s*\w{2,3})*
```

It mean the sentence should start with 2 or 3 letter, 2 or 3 letter as infinite.
Now i should authorise the word blue and yellow.

```
(\w{2,3}|blue|yellow)(,\s*\w{2,3})*
```

It will works inly if blue and yellow are at the beginning

Is there a way to allow the exception's word after comma without repeting the word in the code ?

Comment: Depending on language you are using, you can use recursive pattern.

Comment: Add sentence examples that your regex should be able to understand.

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/dZsZXT/1) what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say go with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65595972/9758194) given by [@Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto), but if your language doesn't support recursive patterns, you could try:

```
^(?![, ])(?:,?\s*\b(?:\w{2,3}|blue|yellow))+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VCJK4s/4)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?![, ])` - Negative lookahead to prevent starting with a comma or space.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group.

  - `,?\b` - Match an optional comma, zero or more space characters and a word-boundary.
  - `(?:` - A nested 2nd non-capture group.

    - `\w{2,3}|blue|yellow` - Lay our your options just once.
    - `)` -Close 2nd non-capture group.
  - `)+` - Close 1st non capture group and match at least once.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Just be aware that `\w{2,3}` allows for things like `__` and `_1_` to be valid inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If the language you are using supports recursive patterns, you can use:

```
^(blue|yellow|\w{2,3})(?:,\s*(?1))*$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/dZsZXT/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If either blue or yellow can occur only once:

`^(?:\w{2,3}\s*,\s*)*(?:blue|yellow)(?:\s*,\s*\w{2,3})*$`

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\w{2,3}\s*,\s*)*` Optionally repeat 2-3 word chars followed by a comma
- `(?:blue|yellow)` Match either blue or yellow
- `(?:\s*,\s*\w{2,3})*` Optionally match a comma and 2-3 word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FWeVjR/1)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking if we should take *"Is there a way to allow the exception's word after comma without repeting the word in the code ?"* as in allowing the word just once or creating the pattern with mentioning the word just once. Either way, kudos =)

Comment: @JvdV Hmm..reading it again I might be wrong. Maybe it should be optional just allowing blue or yellow in the sequence.